# Bug in search results

Tags: bug

I stumbled upon a bug on the search page.

First, I clicked here:
(https://stackoverflow.com/users/718618/c%C3%A9dric-julien)

[image]

Then, this happened:

(https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:718618+[python])
[image]

The HTML of the text below the input field is getting encoded. This does not happen when searching for just "Python", it seems to be an error caused by `user:<id>`

Comment: Woah, big bug, it is not a problem with the user, it's doing it to everyone.